# Elastic Search Using a wildcard within query_string exact search

Tags: elasticsearch, query-string, exact-match

Having an issue trying to get a wildcard into and elastic search exact phrase search using query_string.

Want to allow results to be returned that would be an exact phrase of all variations. i.e. "Coors Brewing", "Coors Brewery", "Coors Brews", etc.

```
POST _search
{
"query": {
  "query_string": {
    "default_operator": "AND", 
    "analyze_wildcard": true,
    "query": "\"coors brew*\""
  }
}
}
```

I am not married to this approach, but would like to search the majority of the document to find the matches vs 1 or 2 fields.

Comment: Keep in mind that your query will match `"Coors Something_I_Didn't_Really_Wanted_To_Be_Matched Brewery"`, because of query analisys. And if I'm not mistaken you should use some fancy analyzer to deal with " chars.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a perfect use case for the `match_phrase_prefix` query ([documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#_match_phrase_prefix)) : did you give it a try?

If you need to make your query on multiple fields at the same time, take a look to the `multi_match` queries with `phrase_prefix` type ([documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-phrase)).

Difference with your wilcard-based `query_string` query is the fact that the match queries aren't parsed and though don't support [query_string syntax](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax).